# Implicit subtype type class resolution

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have defined an implicit class with a shapeless backed method to find an element in a Seq by it's type:

```
implicit class FindByType[L]( l: Seq[L] ) {
  def findByType[A](
    implicit
    typeable: Typeable[A]
  ): Option[A] = l.flatMap( _.cast[A] ).headOption
}
```

I want to implement this function within a class. I know it can be done by:

```
sealed trait A
class A1 extends A

class D(l:Seq[A]) {
  def get[B <: A](implicit typeable: Typeable[B]) = {
    l.findByType[B]
  }
}
```

This is a bit annoying since I end up needing to pass the Typeable implicit around to all of the call sites that aren't called with a concrete B. For example, I can't do the following:

```
trait C {
  type T <: A
}

class C1 extends C {
  type T = A1
}

val cs:List[C] = List(new C1)

val d = new D(Seq(new A1()))

cs.exists{ c => d.get[c.T].isDefined}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like:

```
class D(l:Seq[A]) {
  implicit def typeableForAnyA[F <: A]:Typeable[F] = ???

  def get[F <: A] = {
    l.findByType[F]
  }
}
```

Where I say there is a compile time guarantee for every subtype [some F] of A there is an available `Typeable[F]`. However, I am not sure how to implement `typeableForAnyA` without something like a `ClassTag` which is only a runtime check. Does anyone know how to implement `typeableForAnyA` to give a compile check and save me requiring the implicit `Typeable` for `get`?